# Redirect and removing question mark on URL using htaccess

Tags: htaccess, url-rewriting

When I access my site using `www.example.com/blog` it redirects to `example.com/?/blog`.

How can I remove the question mark, so that the redirection just goes to `example.com/blog`?

My current .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

# Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Can you share your .Htaccess current code and website URL? Do you using php or wordpress?

Comment: My current htaccess can be access on,
http://copasin.com/c/h/56165162eeece

and my website url is https://jefryd.com

I'm using ExpressionEngine Core.

Comment: The code you have posted should not _redirect_ requests for `/blog` (they are internally rewritten). Only if you made a _direct request_ (not an internal rewrite) for `/index.php?/blog` would it be _externally redirect_ to `/?/blog` - at least according to the code above. So, there would seem to be _something else_ triggering this redirect, or you are seeing a cached response?

Answer (score 1):

Notice that you are rewriting URL to: `/index.php?/$1`. After this rewrite is done, the server removes `index.php` from URI. Thereby generating that URL. Just remove the `?` from above rewrite.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Oh ok i get it. But if i remove the `?`, it would appear No files input specified. How can remove the `index.php` include the `?` it self?

Comment: "After this rewrite is done, the server removes `index.php` from URI." - although the `RewriteCond` that checks against `THE_REQUEST` prevents this from happening. Only direct requests to `index.php` should get the `index.php` removed. (?)